# IIS 10, VS 2015:Page rendering fine when run locally but loses styling on publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the code in the default _Layout.cshtml that is added on creation of the project. This is shared by other views.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Mvc/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

All other views are rendered properly when run locally, i.e. they all get the same basic styling when run from the visual studio. But the pages loose styling after I published it using IIS 10.0, yet give me the desired look when run locally. I am using Firefox and Chrome, and not Edge.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Does the user running IIS have read access to the application folders?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your styles and font folder in visual studio and in publish folder. Something might be missing.